# How should I insert data from one table to another dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables, `videos` and `video_views`. I have a column in `videos` which must have the values from `video_views` i.e. for all the views of a particular video in `video_views` it must store it in to `videos`.
This should happen dynamically whenever any update happens in `video_views`.
I tried making stored procedures but no luck.

How should I do this?

Comment: I think you need to use triggers instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just update operation, use

```
 ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

for the foreign keys so whenever there is any update in video_views, that would automatically get updated in the VIDEO table..

By the way, a good approach would be to use the foreign key of video_views table so that you don't need to update records in child table and you won't have any redundant data in the tables.

Comment: Yea.. Will try this. Sounds better. Thanks

Comment: This is one solution.As from what i see your objective is to retrieve the count from videos if you have foreign key relationship between two tables you can retrieve result using inner join

Comment: so your video table will have a foreign key video_views_id